# Adding directories to Lua’s search path

Tags: vimscript-lua

I’m trying to run [Fennel](https://fennel-lang.org/) scripts in Vim 8.1 using the [fennel-nvim](https://github.com/jaawerth/fennel-nvim) plugin. (Fennel is a language that basically lets you write Lua with LISP syntax; you can use it from any Lua-supporting application by dropping in a single Lua file.) The fennel-nvim package is obviously written with Neovim in mind, but I thought maybe it would be simple enough to get it working with Vim anyway.

I’m using the [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager. When I add the line `Plug 'jaawerth/fennel-nvim'` to my vimrc, I get the following error when starting Vim:

```
Error detected while processing /home/bdesham/.vim/plugged/fennel-nvim/plugin/fnl.vim:
line    1:
[string "vim chunk"]:1: module 'patch_searcher' not found:
^Ino field package.preload['patch_searcher']
^Ino file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/patch_searcher.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/patch_searcher/init.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/patch_searcher.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/patch_searcher/init.lua'
^Ino file './patch_searcher.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/patch_searcher.so'
^Ino file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
^Ino file './patch_searcher.so'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The offending line is the first line of `fnl.vim`:

```
lua require("patch_searcher")()
```

The plugin does come with a file called patch_searcher.lua:

```
fennel-nvim
├── FENNEL-LICENSE
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── lua
│   ├── fennel.lua
│   ├── fennelview.lua
│   └── patch_searcher.lua
├── plugin
│   └── fnl.vim
└── README.md
```

It *seems* like I might be able to get this plugin to work with Vim if I can tell the embedded Lua interpreter to add this directory to its “search path,” or whatever this is called in Lua. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Try something akin to the `lua` section in [this qurstion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5290378/9447571). I don't know Lua so I can't vouch for it, but looks like that's a step in the right direction... If you make it work, post it as an answer here yourself. Good luck!

Comment: You can try `lua require("../lua/patch_searcher")()`